# How do I change the textview of a Fragment from WITHIN the fragment itself?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity that creates 3 Fragments. Once I got into the first Fragment, I wish to change the Textview I have in the layout of THIS Fragment, from within this Fragment. I cannot see the 'findViewbyId' method popping up in the IDE when I try to access the TextView this way. Can someone please help me out? Here is the code for the Fragment which I want to carry out the operation in called 'FragmentOne'. The code is for 'FragmentOne.jav'

```
package com.iotaconcepts.aurum;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.iotaconcepts.aurum.R;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class OneFrangment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Fragment fc=getTargetFragment();
        TextView tv=(TextView)fc.findViewById(R.id.textview);//NOT WORKING
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("symp.txt")));
            String parse1;
            while((parse1=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), parse1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tv.setText(parse1 + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tv.append("wtf\n");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SORRY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">
android:w
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Hello"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the inflater.inflate method to a View before you can find views from it.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);
... 
return v;
```